# Dolbeault class of the curvature of the Chern connection equaling the Atiyah class

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

The following is a proposition from Complex Geometry by Huybrechts.

> Proposition $4.3.10$. For the curvature $F_\nabla$ of the Chern connection on an hermitian holomorphic vector bundle $(E,h)$ one has $$[F_\nabla]=A(E) \in H^1(X, \Omega_X \otimes \text{End}(E)).$$

That is, the proposition shows that the Dolbeault cohomology class $[F_\nabla]$ is given by the Atiyah class $A(E)$ defined by the Čech cocycle

$$
A(E)=\{U_{ij},  \psi^{-1}_j\circ(\psi^{-1}_{ij}d\psi_{ij})\circ \psi_i\}
$$

where $\{U_i\}$ is a cover for $X$ with trivializations $\psi_i : E|_{U_i} \to U_i \times \Bbb C^r$.

I have some rather basic questions considering the proof of this. The main point here seems to be a diagram chase for

[image]

which reasons not apparent to me gives the desired conclusion?

Anyway, the proof goes as follows:

> Proof. Let $X=\bigcup_i U_i$ be a covering of $X$ trivializing $E$ via $\psi_i$'s. With respect to $\psi_i$ the hermitian structure $h$ on $U_i$ is given by an hermitian matrix matrix $H_{i}$. Then the curvature $F_{\nabla}$ of the Chern connection on the holomorphic bundle $E$ on $U_{i}$ is given by $$\left.F_{\nabla}\right|_{U_{i}}=\psi^{-1}_i\left(\bar{\partial}\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right)\right) \psi_{i}.$$ Thus, $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \delta_{0}\left(F_{\nabla}\right) & =\left\{U_{i}, \psi_{i}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{\partial}\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right)\right) \circ \psi_{i}\right\} \\
> & =\bar{\partial}\left\{U_{i}, \psi_{i}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right) \circ \psi_{i}\right\},
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> as the maps $\psi_{i}$ are holomorphic trivializations. Hence, it suffices to show that $$
> i\left\{U_{i j}, \psi_{j}^{-1} \circ\left(\psi_{i j}^{-1} d \psi_{i j}\right) \circ \psi_{j}\right\}=\delta_{1}\left\{U_{i}, \psi_{i}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right) \circ \psi_{i}\right\}
> $$ because the cocycle $\left\{U_{i}, \psi_{i}^{-1} \circ\left(\psi_{i j}^{-1} d \psi_{i j}\right) \circ \psi_{j}\right\}$ represents by definition the Atiyah class of $E$. Using the definition of $\delta_{1}$ one shows that the term on the right hand side equals $$
> \left.\left\{U_{i j}, \psi_{j}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{j}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{j}\right) \circ \psi_{j}-\psi_{i}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right) \circ \psi_{i}\right)\right\} .
> $$ Since $$
> \begin{aligned}
> & \psi_{j}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{j}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{j}\right) \circ \psi_{j}-\psi_{i}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right) \circ \psi_{i} \\
> = & \psi_{j}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{j}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{j}-\psi_{i j}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right) \circ \psi_{i j}\right) \circ \psi_{j}
> \end{aligned}
> $$ it suffices to prove $$
> \bar{H}_{j}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{j}-\psi_{i j}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right) \circ \psi_{i j}=\psi_{i j}^{-1} \partial \psi_{i j}
> $$ The latter is a consequence of the compatibility $\psi_{i j}^{\mathrm{t}} H_{i} \bar{\psi}_{i j}=H_{j}$ or, equivalently, $\bar{\psi}_{i j}^{\mathrm{t}} \bar{H}_{i} \psi_{i j}=\bar{H}_{j}$ and the chain rule $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \bar{H}_{j}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{j} & =\psi_{i j}^{-1} \bar{H}_{i}^{-1}\left(\bar{\psi}_{i j}^{\mathrm{t}}\right)^{-1}\left(\bar{\psi}_{i j}^{\mathrm{t}}\left(\partial \bar{H}_{i}\right) \psi_{i j}+\bar{\psi}_{i j}^{\mathrm{t}} \bar{H}_{i} \partial \psi_{i j}\right) \\
> & =\psi_{i j}^{-1}\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right) \psi_{i j}+\psi_{i j}^{-1} \partial \psi_{i j}
> \end{aligned}
> $$ where we have used $\partial \bar{\psi}_{i j}=0$.

I'm able to follow the steps here, except for the first few equations dealing with Čech cocycles due to not being familiar with Čech cohomology.

1. Why does $\psi_i$ being holomorphic trivializations give us a way to pull out $\bar\partial$ from $\delta_{0}\left(F_{\nabla}\right) =\left\{U_{i}, \psi_{i}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{\partial}\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right)\right) \circ \psi_{i}\right\}$?
2. How does one go about showing that $\delta_{1}\left\{U_{i}, \psi_{i}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right) \circ \psi_{i}\right\}$ equals $$
   \left.\left\{U_{i j}, \psi_{j}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{j}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{j}\right) \circ \psi_{j}-\psi_{i}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right) \circ \psi_{i}\right)\right\} .
   $$ using the definition for $\delta_1$?
3. I can't find this notation $\delta_{0}\left(F_{\nabla}\right) =\left\{U_{i}, \psi_{i}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{\partial}\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right)\right) \circ \psi_{i}\right\}$ elsewhere, the boundary operator is usually defined quite differently. How should this be interpreted?
4. Lastly, why is it sufficient to show that $$
   i\left\{U_{i j}, \psi_{j}^{-1} \circ\left(\psi_{i j}^{-1} d \psi_{i j}\right) \circ \psi_{j}\right\}=\delta_{1}\left\{U_{i}, \psi_{i}^{-1} \circ\left(\bar{H}_{i}^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_{i}\right) \circ \psi_{i}\right\}
   $$ as we are not at the level of cohomology yet?

Comment: It would probably make sense to read up on Cech cohomology before asking the question here. Question 2 should simply be by definition of $\delta_1$. For Question 3, $\delta_0$ is simply the canonical map from $H^0$ to $C^0$.

Comment: Regarding Question 1, it should follow since when $\bar\partial$ acts on a section $\alpha s$, where $\alpha$ is a smooth form, and $s$ is a holomorphic section of $E$, then $\bar\partial(\alpha s) = (\bar\partial \alpha) s$.

Comment: Went through the basics yesterday. I've managed to answer 2,3 and 4 myself. The first question is still somewhat mysterious. @RichardLärkäng

Comment: $\psi_i$ maps a holomorphic section to a holomorphic section. $\bar\partial(\bar{H}_i^{-1} \partial \bar{H}_i)$ is a matrix of smooth forms, and $\psi_i^{-1}$ again maps a holomorphic section to a holomorphic section, and is linear over smooth forms.

Comment: Thank you! I guess there is also a minor mistake in the last sentence of the proof. It should be probably the product/Leibniz rule instead of the chain rule? @RichardLärkäng

Comment: Indeed, it seems more appropriate to refer to the product/Leibniz rule.